# Inserting an uploaded file to DB2 Clob using Spring Framework or general JDBC

Tags: java, spring, file-upload, db2, clob

I am trying to upload a file to DB2 Clob column. I am getting the file from user using FormFile. This FormFile object is sent to DAO layer where it has to be inserted. My DAO layer logic is given below,

```
public int uploadRequestDocument(final int requestId, final FormFile requestFile, final String userId) throws EfoneException{
int updatedRowCount = 0;
String sqlQuery = Constants.GFONO_QUERY_ADD_GFONO_REQUEST;
LobHandler lobHandler = new DefaultLobHandler();
final InputStreamReader requestDocumentReader = new InputStreamReader(requestFile.getInputStream());

updatedRowCount = getJdbcTemplate().execute(sqlQuery, new AbstractLobCreatingPreparedStatementCallback(lobHandler) {
@Override
protected void setValues(PreparedStatement stat, LobCreator lobCreator)throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
 stat.setString(1, "1");
 stat.setString(2, "Test");
 stat.setString(3, userId);
 stat.setString(4, userId);
 stat.setInt(5, requestId);
 lobCreator.setClobAsCharacterStream(stat, 6, requestDocumentReader, requestFile.getFileSize());
}
});
```

I tried the below options too but was not fruitful,

```
stat.setCharacterStream(6, requestDocumentReader, requestFile.getFileSize());
stat.setCharacterStream(6, requestDocumentReader, MAX_SIZE);
```

I am always getting the below error message,

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: 
PreparedStatementCallback; SQL 
[insert into GFONO.GFONO_REQUEST_DOC (rqst_doc_num, rqst_doc_loc_num, last_change_userid, create_userid, create_tmstp, last_change_tmstp, efa25_seq_num, rqst_doc)
values (?,?,?,?,CURRENT TIMESTAMP, CURRENT TIMESTAMP, ?,?)];
DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -302, SQLSTATE: 22001, SQLERRMC: null;
nested exception is com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.SqlException: DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -302, SQLSTATE: 22001, SQLERRMC: null
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:101)
```

Please suggest on what I am missing and help me resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I am using DB2 8.1 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error code says:

```
THE VALUE OF INPUT VARIABLE OR PARAMETER NUMBER position-number IS INVALID OR 
TOO LARGE FOR THE TARGET COLUMN OR THE TARGET VALUE
```

You said that you try to insert file into CLOB. Try to use BLOB...

Comment: Thank you for the response. The file I am trying to upload is Just 1 byte. I do not have access to alter the database table. You mean to say, files that needs to be saved to database table should be done using blob and not clob?

Comment: Yes CLOB is a character large object, i.e. a massive string;

BLOB is binary large object i.e. .jpg, .docx

Comment: If your file is of some txt-like format, you can read it in the java ans store the text only(if that covers the requirement).